# HorizontalScrollView vs Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, horizontalscrollview

I see that the the gallery widget was deprecated because it cannot reuse views. I researched that they would suggest horizontal scrollview as an alternative. Is there any difference since horizontal scrollview also don't reuse view?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much difference except that you could make same stuff easier with horizontal scrolling

Comment: how is it easier? in gallery it can have an adapter that can easily track what image(s) were clicked,that can easily change,add ,delete images

Comment: yea that is a better side of that , but its much less pain in the ass  to do that with horizontal scroll , but evrything depends on your needs , if u dont need anything complex , then you can use horizontal scroll , if you want , ill provide you some advanced script for that , (all customized , no scrollbars .. etc)

Answer (score 0):

The Gallery class was deprecated in API level 16 and thus no longer supported.

So you'll have to use HorizontalScrollView or ViewPager.